# Moved my React Native project folder to a new machine, how do i get it to run?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I recently cloned my React Native project folder from GitHub to my new/unused Mac. I am now in the root directory and when i run `"react-native run-ios"` to get the project going and load up the phone simulator, i get `-bash: react-native: command not found`

Do i need to re-install EVERY single dependency in package.json again (because it seems they're all there in my folders)?

Whats's the minimum in need to get my project up and running again and what commands do i use with my current project. I don't want to have to 'react-native init' an entirely new project!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done any react-native work on the Mac, then yes, you need to install all the dependencies including the react-native cli. You don't have the cli for react-native installed and you are trying to use it. You need to install react-native cli and NPM and make sure all dependencies are there.

Comment: Ok, partly wrong. I had to install brew, node, watchman, react-native-cli. Then navigate to  my folder, and run "react-native run-ios". Done! Glad i checked before reinstalling all the dependencies!!!! Nightmare avoided